# how to enable a control like dropdownlist which is inside a panel that is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I Have a panel that is disabled. And hence all the controls inside the panel are disabled. On Postback I need to enable only one control which is inside a disabled panel. Please let me know how we can achieve this. Below is the Code

```
 <asp:Panel ID="testPanel" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Codebehind aspx.cs

```
testpanel.Enabled = false;
dropdownlist.Enavbled=true;
```

Here the dropdownlist is not getting enabled.
Please let me know a way to enable it. Iterating through panel is a performance as I have many controls inside it. So I need a better way to enable the DropDownList inside a Disabled Panel.

Comment: You can't show child element unless you show parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot enable a single control in a container control that is disabled because [that property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is inherited (in the same manner as [`Visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). So the only way is to enable the `Panel` and this control but disable all other controls in the panel.

```
dropdownlist.Enabled = true;
testpanel.Enabled = dropdownlist.Enabled;
// disable all other controls in the panel
TextBox1.Enabled = false;
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This property propagates down the control hierarchy. If you disable a
>   container control, the child controls within that container are also
>   disabled. For more information, see the [`IsEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.isenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Thank You. Will change the way u have suggested